# How can I set position independent build setting using xcodebuild from the command line?

Tags: command-line, xcodebuild, build-settings

I'm working with some third party tools that generate xcode project files for a few subcomponents.  Their tools generate the project files with Generate Position-Dependent Code set to YES (potentially because the tool generates project files for OS X builds too and the latest update has it confused).

While I could simply turn these flags off in the GUI, it's not as convenient as my build process is scripted to generate each project file, build it, move binaries around, lipo them together, etc.

I'm fairly sure these settings can be overridden on the command line, but I'm curious as to what the setting key actually is.  For instance, I don't know if the setting=value means that the setting name is verbatim to how it displays in Xcode (Generate Position-Dependent Code), as there are spaces in it.

If anyone can provide a listing of all settings that can be passed to xcodebuild, that would be super.

Comment: The setting name is actually `GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC` - "Generate Position-Dependent Code" is just the description.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  Write it as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: Glad it helped - I've converted the comment to an answer now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting name is actually `GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC`. "Generate Position-Dependent Code" is just the description.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, when I copy (Command+C) that setting when it is highlighted in project *Build Settings*...
[image]
...then paste into Text Edit I see the actual command line setting key.

```
//:configuration = Debug

//:configuration = Release

//:completeSettings = some
GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC
```

That works for all build settings, too.